# Why xargs uses -t to enable verbose mode?

Tags: xargs, gnu, options

Most programs use `-v` to enable verbose mode. Why does the GNU `xargs` use `-t` to enable verbosity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

And the shell uses `-x` (this is short for "execution trace").

For `xargs`, the `-t` option enables "trace mode", i.e. it will show you what it's doing by printing the commands that it is executing.  Tracing is just another ways of "being verbose".  Note that tracing the execution of commands is a *particular* way of being verbose, as verbosity in other commands (such as GNU `mv`) doesn't really show the commands being executed but just tells you that it's doing *something*.

You will also notice that the GNU `xargs` utility has a `--verbose` option, which is a synonym for `-t`.

Comment: The shell also has `-v` for "verbose", though it's perhaps not as useful for debugging as `-x` is.

Comment: @ilkkachu Ah yes, I forgot about that (since I never use it). It will just make the shell output whatever it's reading as input (i.e. the source of the current script).

Comment: @K, yeah, I didn't even remember how hilariously useless it is.